# sudoers file and passwd only for selected group

Tags: sudo, password, root, group

I have 3 users in "production" group: John, Steve and Bob.
In "sales" group are: Sam and Jack.

Now, I would like to give John permition to change passwords of all users but only in "production" group, so he will be unable to make any changes to Sam and Jack.

In my /etc/sudoers file I have alias for all users in "production" group:

```
User_Alias  PRODUCTION = %production
```

And the problem is I have no idea how to write this:

```
john ALL =(root) /usr/bin/passwd steve, (root) /usr/bin/passwd bob, (root) /usr/bin/passwd jack
```

... using my PRODUCTION alias, so if there is someone new added to this group, there will be no need to add him manually to sudoers file too.

I've tried something like this in many variations:

```
john ALL =(root) /usr/bin/passwd PRODUCTION
```

but it doesn't work and at this moment I have no more ideas.

I will appreciate any clues, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too complicated for `sudoers`.

You have to write a script which checks whether the user belongs to this group and calls `passwd` if so.

`sudoers` must then be configured so that `john` can run this script as root. Of course, the path to this script must be writable only for `root`.

```
#! /bin/bash

group="groupname"

test $# -ne 1 && exit 2

user="$1"

if id "$user" | grep -qF "(${group})"; then
        echo passwd "$user"
else
        echo "User '${user}' is not in group '${group}'."
fi
```

called as

```
./testscript username
```

Comment: `id mb | grep -q "(${group})"` is wrong but I don't know what you intended to write. I expect you meant to pass some flags instead of a user name, but which flags result in group names in parentheses?

Comment: @Gilles id (GNU coreutils) 8.23: `id hl` output: `uid=1000(hl) gid=1001(hauke) groups=100(users),1001(hauke)`

Comment: So should this be `id -- "$user" | sed 's/^[^ ]*//' | grep -F "(${group})"`? I don't understand where you're getting `mb` from. The `sed` call is to remove the username (in case there's a group by the same name), `grep -F` is in case the group name contains grep metacharacters such as `.`. Why not use `id -gn; id -Gn` for output that's easier to parse?

Comment: @Gilles I'm sorry... I was so focused on the parentheses that I didn't realize the real problem: `mb` is the local account I used for testing. I just forgot to replace that.

Answer (score 0):

I know this query is 2 yrs old, but I did find an answer that does not involve a script.

You should use `visudo` to update the `/etc/sudoers` file.  See `sodoers(5)` man page.  You should see an example that you should be able to leverage pretty easily:

```
    USER HOST = /usr/bin/passwd [A-Za-z]*, !/usr/bin/passwd root
```

*The user(s) defined as USER is allowed to change anyone's password except for root on the HOST machine(s).  Note that this assumes passwd(1) does not take multiple usernames on the command line.*